# I am getting a data source error running seal report on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, dsn

I am getting a Datasource error while trying to run a seal report on IIS server.
The error reads ,

```
'ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified'
```

How can I configure a datasource on IIS and make sure my seal report is able to use it.

The sample seal reports are working very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't configure it in IIS.

You need to configure a System Level Datasource using the ODBC manager, which I believe is located in Control Panel/Admin Tools

Comment: You are the best. Thanks so much, it has worked, you dont know how many hours I have spent troubleshooting this. Thanks again